# Controller for a DC motor for moving 18 cm constantly

Tags: microcontroller, pid-controller, digital-control

I am working on designing a micro mouse that solves a maze. The objective is to reach the centre of the maze. The mouse needs to move one block distance at a time, which is 18 m. Currently, I am using a position control which calculates the error in distance and converts that into PWM value. So, as the error gets lower, the PWM decreases. Below is the code for it:

```
if( distanceRight < 60 || distanceLeft < 60)    // Encoder Pulses from the left and the right wheel
        {
            //Finding the error and converting into fraction values to be used as PWM 
            errorRight = (60.0 - distanceRight)/60; 
            errorLeft = (60.0 - distanceLeft)/60;

            PWM_RightWheel = (errorRight);  
            PWM_LeftWheel = (errorLeft);            

            distanceRight = abs(encoder1.getPulses());
            distanceLeft = abs(encoder2.getPulses());
        }
```

But, here is the problem. Sometimes the mouse overshoots due to its inertia. The encoder that I am using to measure the distance has a max of 48 state changes for one revolution. Considering the radius of the wheel, this gives me the ability to measure 0.25cm distances accurately.

**What kind of controller can I use to reduce the problem of overshoot?** This overshoot problem also occurs when I use the encoders to calculate distance while turning right or left. Again, in both the cases, sometimes I have the problem of overshoot.

Do I need to use a PID controller? If yes then how can I find the transfer function for the motion of the wheel and implement it in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only using distance remaining as your control variable.

You also need to use velocity, that is, rate of arrival of pulses, or number of pulses per sample cycle.

You can then use that to calculate your required speed/deceleration rate and come to a halt where you desire, possibly even back driving the motor(s) to act as a brake if need be.

Comment: So, does that mean we need to use a PD controller? Since if we use velocity, then that would be a differential of distance. Right?

Comment: @sangam yes you need the differential.

Comment: That was my second part of the question. How do I get the transfer function for the DC motor to calculate the Kd and Kp?

Comment: I'm not sure what your are coding the above in. So I can't really answer that.

Comment: I am using an MBed microcontroller and I am coding it in C. Will this help? Also I tried using the link [here](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2011/05/15/designing-the-motor-controller/) to design the PD controller but it did not seem to work.

Comment: @sangam you need to figure out the math and the acceleration and deceleration rate that you can reasonably expect from your setup and a scheme to implement all that.